# Android socket client readUTF not working

Tags: java, android, sockets, stream

I'm new to Java socket programming and I am doing a basic socket communication between an Android client and a Java server on the PC side. The server could receive the message from the client, but the client seems to have trouble reading messages from the server. I've been wondering why this is happening.

Server:

```
while(true){
   try {
    socket = serverSocket.accept();

    dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("ip: " + socket.getInetAddress());
    System.out.println("message: " + dataInputStream.readUTF());

    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Hello Client !!!!!!" + "\n");
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
...
...

   if (socket != null){
    try{
        socket.close();
        socket = null;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Client:

```
socket = new Socket(serverIP, 8080);
dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dataOutputStream.writeUTF(textOut.getText().toString());

dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, dataInputStream.readUTF());
            textIn.setText(dataInputStream.readUTF());
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    });
```

On server side everything works fine but the Android client just can't receive the data. readUTF does not return anything (also returns a W/System.err in the logcat)

## Solution:

I finally resolved the problem by moving the dataInputStream.readUTF() out of the runOnUIThread section. eg. Store it in a temporary string before runOnUiThread. I guess this should be a noob mistake.

Also calling readUTF() in a row was definitely stupid enough.

Comment: It still is. The problem isn't where it was called. The problem was that you were calling it twice. I already told you that.

Comment: I'm sorry for my lack of understanding sir. But would you please tell me which part of my code is calling the readUTF twice? I apologize since I have no previous knowledge on network.

Comment: You have two calls to `readUTF()` in a row. Surely you can see that? Once where you log it, and another where you put it into a text field.

Comment: Ah I see I actually deleted that line later. However, I tried just calling readUTF once in the runOnUIThread, still not working. But once I moved it out of it like I said, it now works fine. I guess it means calling socket functions inside the runOnUiThread would be unwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the Android client just can't receive the data

Your client tries to read two messages, but only one is sent.

Also your server never closes the connection.